# extracting a coefficient from formal power series multiplication

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The Questions is Compute the value of $[x^n] \frac{(1+x)^n}{1-x} $

The solution is as follows:

$[x^n] \frac{(1+x)^n}{1-x} $ = $[x^n](1+x)^n(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + . . . ) $

=  $\sum_{k=0}^n [x^k](1+x)^n * [x^{n-k}](1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + . . . ) $

=  $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(1)$

= $2^n $

Could someone please explain how this sum is formed?

Answer (score 2):

The term involving $x^n$ is a sum of terms each of which is a product of a coefficient times $x^k$ from the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ and a coefficient times $x^{n-k}$ from the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$. For each $k$, the latter coefficient is $1$, while for each $k$, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^n$ is $\binom{n}{k}$. Add these up over all $k$ and you get the formula you gave.

Comment: This makes sense, so generally speaking when multiplying two formal power series in closed form, will it always be $ \sum_{k=0}^n [x^k] a * [x^{n-k}] b $? a and b being formal power series.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
S(n)
&=[x^n] \frac{(1+x)^n}{1-x}
\qquad\text{want coefficient of }x^n\\
&=[x^n](1+x)^n\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m
\qquad\text{expand } \dfrac1{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n [x^k](1+x)^n  [x^{n-k}]\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m
\qquad\text{for each }0\le k \le n
\text{ look at separate terms in the product}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\cdot 1 
\qquad [x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k},  [x^{n-k}]\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m=1\\
&=2^n
\qquad \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: thanks for the reply, this helps me out, Can you also help me out with this one? $[x^n] (x^k)(1-x)^{-k} $

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations